# Java ArrayList adding an element

Tags: java

Why does this line of code in my Tree class not work. I get an error on the add(child).

```
    public void addChild(TreeNode<T> parent, TreeNode<T> child)
{
    parent.children.add(child);
}
```

Here is TreeNode

```
public class TreeNode<E> {

protected int accountNum;
protected ArrayList<E> children;
```

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: ... or a compiler error? Which?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because children is an `ArrayList` of `E`, not of `TreeNode<E>`, while child is a `TreeNode<E>`.

Depends on your needs, it could be either:

```
public void addChild(TreeNode<T> parent, T child)
```

Or:

```
protected ArrayList<TreeNode<E>> children;
```

Comment: Downvoter - I would appreciate a comment that will expand my knowledge.

Comment: @Nate - thanks. I just wanted to know why someone considered this answer as a bad one, it's harder to learn when no one tells you...

Comment: Yeah, I wish it was possible to see *who* voted what and not just counts.  I've only been on here a couple weeks and had someone with a grudge to down vote multiple of my *accepted* answers, just to be a jerk :\

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to add of an instance of `TreeNode<T>` to a list that's probably not bounded with a `TreeNode<T>` type. E.g.

```
TreeNode<Integer> parent = new TreeNode<Integer>();
TreeNode<Integer> child = new TreeNode<Integer>();
```

Then the instance member of `parent` becomes: `ArrayList<Integer> children = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

In effect, `addChild` becomes `void addChild(TreeNode<Integer> parent, TreeNode<Integer> child)` and you say:

```
node.children.add(child); //NO
node.children.add(new Integer()); //YES
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need this:

```
public <N, T extends TreeNode<N>> void addChild(TreeNode<T> parent, T child){
    parent.children.add(child);
}
```

then you can:

```
     TreeNode<TreeNode<String>> parent = new TreeNode<TreeNode<String>>();
    TreeNode<String> child = new TreeNode<String>();
    addChild(parent, child);
```